# Eigenfunction of Laplacian

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, sp.spectral-theory, operator-theory

On $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ it is true that $\Delta$ has $\sigma(\Delta)=(-\infty,0].$ Also, there are no eigenfunction. Yet, even if one would not know this, negativity $\langle \Delta u,u \rangle \le 0$ does immediately imply that there could only be such functions satisfying $\Delta u = \lambda u$ for $\lambda \le 0.$

If we change the setting from $L^2$ to $C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$, the continuous functions tending to zero, is there a similar argument why $\Delta u = \lambda u$ is only possible for $\lambda \le 0$ and perhaps: Are there any such eigenfunctions?

Comment: I think that both Ian and I were thrown off by the notation $C_0$. I guess that you do not mean compactly supported, but rather that there is a compact exhaustion $K_n$ so that $\sup\{ |f(x)|: x \in R^n-K_n\}$ tends to zero. This set of functions is not be contained in $L^2$ (and hence not a dense subset).

Comment: Also, could you be more specific of your definition of Laplacian? If you had assumed $C^2$, then it would be clear. If you use $L^2$ then I assume that you are taking the (unique) self-adjoint extension of the Laplacian acting on compactly supported smooth functions.

Comment: @ChrisJudge yes, I think it is also clearly stated in my question that I am not talking about compactly supported but , exactly as you state it, the ones tending to infinity.

Comment: @ChrisJudge $\Delta: D(\Delta) \subset C_0(\mathbb{R}^d) \rightarrow C_0(\mathbb{R}^d)$ where $D(\Delta)= \left\{ f \in C_0; \Delta f \in C_0 \right\}.$

Comment: How do I know whether $\Delta f \in C_0$ if I don't know what $\Delta f$ means? Would like to think of each $f \in C_0$ as a distribution, and then $\Delta f$ as the Laplacian on distributions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can find all the tempered distributions $u$ such that $\Delta u=\lambda u$ (thus, including continuous functions going to $0$ at infinity, since these are locally integrable): taking Fourier transform, $(r^2+\lambda)\widehat{u}=0$. Unless $\lambda$ is real and non-positive, this implies that the support of $\widehat{u}$ is empty, hence $u=0$. For $\lambda$ non-positive, this implies that the support of $\widehat{u}$ is on the sphere (spherical shell) $S$ of radius $\sqrt{-\lambda}$. For example, taking $\widehat{u}$ to be the distribution given by integration over that sphere, gives a continuous function
$$
u(x) \;=\; {1\over (2\pi)^n} \int_S e^{i\xi\cdot x}\;d\xi
$$
Since this is rotationally invariant, take $x=(x_1,0,\ldots,0)$, and, up to irrelevant constants $c$, 
$$
u(x_1,0,\ldots,0)\;=\; c\cdot \int_{-1}^1 (-\lambda-\xi_1^2)^{{n-3\over 2}} \,e^{i\xi_1x_1}\;d\xi_1
$$
For $n\ge 2$, this is the Fourier transform on $\mathbb R$ of the $L^1$ function that is $0$ outside $[-1,1]$ and $(-\lambda-\xi_1^2)^{{n-3\over 2}}$ inside the interval. Thus, by Riemann-Lebesgue, it is continuous and goes to $0$ at infinity, as desired. Again, this succeeds for every $\lambda\le 0$. (And this spherically symmetrical solution is related to Bessel functions, I think.)

And we know that every distribution supported on the sphere is the composition of normal derivatives with distributions *on* the sphere. Distributions *on* the sphere have expansions in spherical harmonics (converging in Sobolev spaces).

EDIT: it doesn't change the conclusion, but I had the wrong exponent $(n-2)/2$, rather than $(n-3)/2$ (which I just changed it to), due to hastiness in converting the surface integral to a one-dimensional integral.

Also, the "obvious" way to evaluate Fourier transform of a compactly-supported distribution (by applying it to the exponentials) is provably correct (and this is standard, but should not be overlooked), because such distributions extend continuously to the larger (Frechet) space of smooth functions (from the smaller space of test functions, e.g.).

Comment: For example, the Bessel function $J_{0}(|x|)$ decays at $\infty$ and defines a smooth eigenfunction on the real plane. Its decay is of order $|x|^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ and so it's not in $L^2$ (as must be true.)

Comment: And another silly error: it's not the interval $[-1,1]$ that matters, but $[-\sqrt{-\lambda},\sqrt{\lambda}]$... but it did not seem worthwhile to kick this thing to the top of the queue for such a silly error.